# how to specify IEDriverServer and geckoDriver in conf.js

Tags: protractor, geckodriver, selenium-iedriver

As I know, with latest protractor, we can specify `chromeDriver` and `seleniumServerJar` in `conf.js`. So can we specify `IEDriverServer` and `geckoDriver`  in `conf.js` as well? If yes, how to config them?

Comment: help!! help!! help!!